# Microsoft Band 2 RSS feed always says Data fetch error

Tags: xml, rss, microsoft-band

I have a Microsoft Band 2 and i'm trying to load an RSS feed into a webtile, but it always says "Data fetch error, There seems to be something wrong with the data for this tile... try again later"

- The XML was read by the Microsoft Band Tile Creator successfully, and let me design my tile and deploy it to my device without an issue.
- The XML validates on w3.
- The XML loads and gets formatted inside a web browser, telling me it's readable, but this is all my tile ever says.

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<channel>
    <atom:link href="[this was linked to a private feed before posting on stackoverflow]" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
    <title>test</title>
    <link>http://www.microsoft.com/</link>
    <description>Test</description>
    <language>en-us</language>
    <ttl>1</ttl>
    <item>
        <guid>http://www.microsoft.com/</guid>
        <pubDate>Mon, 29 Feb 2016 08:00:00 EST</pubDate>
        <title>TEST TITLE</title>
        <description>Testing</description>
        <link>http://www.microsoft.com/</link>
    </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

My manifest:

```
{
"manifestVersion": 1,
"name": "Test tile",
"description": "Test tile",
"version": 1,
"versionString": "1",
"author": "MRW",
"organization": "MRW",
"contactEmail": "",
"tileIcon": {
  "46": "icons/tileIcon.png"
},
"badgeIcon": {
  "24": "icons/badgeIcon.png"
},
"icons": {},
"refreshIntervalMinutes": 30,
"tileTheme": {
  "base": "ffaf00",
  "highlight": "ffaf00",
  "lowlight": "f99a03",
  "secondary": "9e9678",
  "highContrast": "ffa500",
  "muted": "bc8b00"
},
"resources": [
  {
    "url": "[this was linked to a private feed before posting on   stackoverflow]",
    "style": "Feed",
    "content": {
      "_1_title": "title",
      "_1_description": "description"
      }
  }
 ],
"pages": [
    {
      "layout": "MSBand_ScrollingText",
      "condition": "true",
      "textBindings": [
        {
          "elementId": "1",
          "value": "{{_1_title}}"
        },
        {
          "elementId": "2",
          "value": "{{_1_description}}"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "notifications": [
    {
      "condition": "{{_1_title}} != \"now\"",
      "title": "{{_1_title}}",
      "body": "{{_1_description}}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is my Microsoft Band 2 not able to fetch from the internet, possibly? Is there something to check?

As far as my XML -- Am I missing something? Are there some other XML requirements for the Band 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Band 2 sends a "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0" request header.

Unfortunately most hosting providers have mod_security enabled which blocks that header.

A valid header is "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT)", "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (test)" or even "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 ()"

You have to reconfigure mod_security or disable it.